# C# function that calls a SQL stored procedure works when used from local machine but fails when called from an Azure function in the cloud

Tags: c#, function, azure

I created this C# file that takes a JSON document as input, processes data and then sends the processed data to an SQL database. The eventuall plan is to put it in the cloud as an Azure function with a trigger for any new document entering an Azures CosmosDB.

Currently the part of the code responsible for sending the information to SQL looks like this:

```
public void Store (PushData i)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=<serverconnection>;DataBase=<DBName>;User ID=<ID>;Password=<PW>"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ActualsCreator", conn);

            // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", i.Date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailabilityTime", i.MinutesUptime);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnvName", i.EnvName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeaName", i.MeaName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MeaType", i.MeaType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUpdate", i.LastUpd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClusterStatus", i.Status);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceID", i.ResID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MidnightTime", i.MinutesUptimeForMidnight);

            // execute the command
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

When run localy all the information makes it to the SQL server without an issue, however when run from the azure function it will fail at "@MeaName" or "@EnvName" or "@ResourceID".

```
[Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.monitorResultFullTrigger. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Procedure or function 'ActualsCreator' expects parameter '@MeaName', which was not supplied.
```

Whichever one fails is whichever one is stated first in the code. The only thing these 3 have in common over all the other types is they are stored as nvarchar(50) in the SQL database. The error message indicates that nothing is being passed to the parameter, but the exact same code doesnt have this issue localy, and none of the other variables but those 3 have this issue either.

My question is what can cause this? Why does it only fail in the Azure function when in the cloud and why only the nvarchar types.

Comment: Since `SqlConnection` only works with [tag:sql-server] (On prem and Azure variants), why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: Also, you've misread the error. It's not saying nothing has been passed to the parameter, it's saying the parameter doesn't exist at all. It's odd and difficult to reconcile with the code show. This is the sort of error that is often found when there's inappropriate *sharing* of database objects, but the ones you're showing are all locally controlled. Definitely no other section of code that may try to call the same stored proc? (Also, if you're just calling a SP and not expecting results, you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` rather than `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Be sure that the SQL Server has "Allow access to Azure Services" checked under firewall. I've previously seen a similar issue due to this.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever No other code is calling the SP, also it only fails on those 3 specific parameters the others which are treated the same in the code pass fine. the "i.MeaName" is just a struct where the data is stored, if i hardcode and store a string inside "i.MeaName" itl work both localy and on azure, but if i store a string variable inside "i.MeaName" itl only work on local. Its why this problem is so confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify the `SqlDbType` in our code, we can do like below:

```
SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("@MeaName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = i.MeaName };
cmd.Parameters.Add(para);
```

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Ya i tried that aswel as changing the character type in the SQL database from nvarchar to just char and varchar. All combinations of the above worked localy, failed on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the below one for all the parameters

```
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"ActualsCreator", sqlConnection))
                {
                   //define sqlcommandtype as SP
                    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                   //define induvidual parameters for the SP
                    SqlParameter Param_MeaName = sqlCommand.CreateParameter();
                    Param_MeaName.ParameterName = @"@MeaName";
                    Param_MeaName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
                    Param_MeaName.Size = 50;
                    Param_MeaName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    Param_MeaName.Value = i.MeaName;

                    //Add the paramters in the sqlcommand
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(Param_Order_Key);

                    //Open the connection
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    //Execute the SP
                    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: @Delay67 could you post you `storedprocedure` code ( just the create command with the parameters ) and also table schema. So that I can able to repro from my end